How to push on docker registry your image with other services inside
I'm running an application through docker compose:
version: "3.8"

services:
  lorem:
    container_name: lorem
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - "./output:/output"
      - "./input:/input"
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
    networks:
      - "backend"
    depends_on:
      - redis-stack

  redis-stack:
    container_name: redis-stack
    image: redis/redis-stack:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
      - "8001:8001"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "--raw", "incr", "ping"]
    networks:
      - backend

  rq-dashboard:
    container_name: rq-dashboard
    image: cjlapao/rq-dashboard:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      RQ_DASHBOARD_REDIS_URL: redis://host.docker.internal:6379
    ports:
      - "9181:9181"
    depends_on:
      - redis-stack

  prometheus:
    container_name: prometheus
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    ports:
      - target: 9090
        published: 9090
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./prometheus/prometheus.yml
        target: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
    networks:
      - backend

  pushgateway:
    image: prom/pushgateway:latest
    container_name: pushgateway
    ports:
      - "9091:9091"
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    networks:
      - backend

  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - target: 3000
        published: 3000
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    name: "backend"
    driver: "bridge"

and this is an example of my docker file
FROM python:3.10-slim
LABEL maintainer="**"
LABEL version="development"
LABEL repository="lorem"



WORKDIR /app

COPY lorem ./lorem_core
COPY ./scripts ./scripts
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.toml poetry.lock entry.sh ./
COPY ./docs /app/docs

#ARG GITLAB_TOKEN
#ENV GITLAB_TOKEN=${GITLAB_TOKEN}


RUN pip install poetry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false

RUN poetry install --with wrappers,docs

#ENV GITLAB_TOKEN=""

CMD ["./entry.sh"]

What is the best way to publish this and make it like a single image? I would like that anyone could just pull "lorem" and have everything it needs to work like redis etc. (so without using the docker compose / other configs)
I didn't try anything particular yet, I tought it would be easy and straightforward

This seems similar to How to distribute docker-compose files?  You can't compile multiple images into a single image, or embed the Compose file into an image; the usual approach is to push your application as its own image to some repository, separately distribute the Compose file, and let the remote Docker download image:s as needed.
